# User does not have the right roles. Laravel-permission

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I'm using laravel-permission pack (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). 
And I keep getting this error only when I'm accessing add.posts.view and edit.posts.view. I have index, tags, categories and everything works fine.
I don't know if there's a problem with my code or the other ones are working because they do not have a role set.

Error:

```
Spatie \ Permission \ Exceptions \ UnauthorizedException
User does not have the right roles.
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin']], function(){
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'], function(){
    Route::get('', ['as'=>'admin.post.index', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@index']);
    Route::get('add', ['as'=>'admin.post.add', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@add']);
    Route::post('save', ['as'=>'admin.post.save', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@store']);
    Route::get('{post}/edit', ['as'=>'admin.post.edit', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@edit']);
    Route::put('{post}/update', ['as'=>'admin.post.update', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@update']);
    Route::get('delete{post}', ['as'=>'admin.post.delete', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@delete']);
    Route::get('{post}/show', ['as'=>'admin.post.show', 'uses'=>'Admin\PostController@show']);
```

I have two folders for admin and editor. everythings is the same for both (for now).

Add Function:

```
public function add()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $tags = Tag::all();
    $post = new Post;
    return view('posts.add')->with('post')->withCategories($categories)->withTags($tags);

}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: What are `add.posts.view` and `edit.posts.view`?

Comment: they're the views of my laravel application, the pages where i put my form to add posts to system or edit posts.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mentioned your views in this context.  But, it seems clear that the routes you entered here have a role:admin restriction on them.

Comment: I mentioned because in the only two views there's showing the error. The index view are working just fine. I set the role to admin in my seed, so the user who's accessing this routes is a admin user.

Comment: The views don't contain business logic, or shouldn't, so you're looking at the wrong thing when trying to diagnose a problem with roles.

Comment: Ok, I'm a beginner so its a little bit hard for me. What should we be looking? The User Model? Or even the Handler?

Comment: It's probably going to be over your head.  I can't tell you where the problem is, you'd need to debug further.